Replace strings in AndroidManifest.xml using shell
I want to replace something in AndroidManifest.xml using shell script.
I use MPatcher tool to run .sh scripts on Android. My problem is that I can't replace those string:
    <uses-permission

        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

With:
    <uses-permission

        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Игра станет хранить миры по старому пути благодаря методу Egornya. -->

    <uses-permission

        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

I've tried a lot of things, nothing works. Either it issues an error, or it writes successfully replaced, but nothing has changed.
Examples of codes:
sed -i '/<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/>/{

    i\

    <!-- Игра станет хранить миры по старому пути благодаря методу Egornya. -->\

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />\

}' "$MANIFEST_PATH"


sed -i '/<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/>/ {

    s/.*/<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/>\

    <!-- Игра станет хранить миры по старому пути благодаря методу Egornya. -->\

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/>/

}' "$MANIFEST_PATH"


sed -i '/<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/>/ { s/.*/<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/> <!-- Игра станет хранить миры по старому пути благодаря методу Egornya. --> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \/>/ }' "$MANIFEST_PATH"

so can someone give me a working code? I just can't do anything with it.
Even ChatGPT can't help.

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

Without a proper [mre] it's hard to point to a specific duplicate. Generally don't use traditional regex tools to edit structured formats like XML.

From the data you posted, the uses-permission tag comprises two lines in the XML file, but your sed command assumes that it is in a single line. BTW, I find your posting difficult to read -it's hard to see what is code and what is just your comment. Please fix your formatting.

@user1934428 comment was Fixed. Btw what should I use instead of "sed" then?

The duplicate already answers exactly that question.

@tripleee Absolutely not. the question that allegedly is the answer to my question about how a person wanted to DELETE an entire block containing some word, while I need to REPLACE one line with several other lines. These are COMPLETELY different things.

The question was "what should I use instead of sed"; but fine, I added a second duplicate. Going forward, you are expected to figure out how to adapt the information from a duplicate to your problem.
